# Clear Contents of File from cmd

Tags: cmd

I have a file named testFile.js. js file contains some javascript code. I wanted to know how do I delete the file content alone from command Prompt (Windows).What is the command I should use?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at the command prompt assuming you're already in the directory containing the file.

```
echo.> testFile.js
```

Comment: It is clearing the file contents. But creating one empty space line.How to delete that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of my previous answer try this.

```
del testFile.js
COPY CON testFile.js
```

You will get just a blinking cursor. Press F6 and then enter. Your zero byte file will be created.

Comment: Thanks :) It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This will clear the file completely:

```
TYPE NUL > testFile.js
```